# reset_counters not works for not association field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter-cache

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_counters

I have a field called `sequence` in my model. I want to reset all sequences of particular record set and update all sequences one by one `1`. But while using `reset_counter` I'm getting `has no association called 'sequence'`. Here is my code block

```
ids = [1,2,4,6,7]
Group.reset_counters(ids, "sequence")
Group.increment_counter(sequence, ids)
```

Is it any way to update given ids sequence by 1 (each id sequence should be updated by 1 to the previous id)?

PS: `update_attribute` is taking time for updating individual records. so i want to update records in bulk.

Comment: If you're trying to update sequence column of a model Group then [`update_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)  - `Group.where(id: ids).update_all(sequence: 1)`

Comment: @Surya this will update all sequence to 1. I want to update sequence increment sequence by 1 to the previous records

Comment: @AnkitaAgrawal : Provide Group model code and the association on which sequence is updated when cached.

Comment: @Surya It dont have a sequence association. It has a Sequence as a column_name

Comment: Did you try [`update_counters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update_counters)?

Comment: @31piy update_counters will update sequence by 1 with existing id sequence. I want to reset that and update all records one by one